# Problem with the selection of a searched item in a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm making an app in Flutter about clothes registry. One of the functionalities is that the user can search by words and the clothes that contain the entered words in the name appear on the screen, so the user can select it to see its information.
The problem appears when the user clicks on a garment because the following exception occurs `Exception has occurred.ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<RopaManager> above this SliverGrid Widget` in the following part of the code (This code corresponds to the screen that displays all items (PrendaGrid)):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: prendas.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
              child: PrendaThumbnail(prenda: prendas[index]),
              onTap: () {
                final manager = Provider.of<RopaManager>(context, listen: false); //here occurs the exception
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return PrendaScreen(
                        item: prendas[index],index: index, manager: manager );
                  }
                  )
                );
```

For the search I do it in the following way:
When I click on the search button I delegate in a class `MySearhDelegate`

```
               IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(context: context, delegate: MySearchDelegate(manager: manager));
                },
```

And the class has the `buildResults` method as follows:

```
final normalizeSearch = _normalizeString("$query");
          List<Ropa> prendasCoincidentes = [];
          for (Ropa prenda in manager.ropaItems) {
            if (_normalizeString(prenda.name).contains(normalizeSearch))
              prendasCoincidentes.add(prenda);
          }
          if (prendasCoincidentes.isNotEmpty) {
            return PrendaGrid(prendas: prendasCoincidentes);
          }
```

In `buildResults` I have also tried to return `Consumer<RopaManager>` but the application crashes.